# How do I install grub on a drive separate from my root partition?

Tags: arch-linux, partition, grub, boot-loader

I currently, have a root partition from an arch install I did before, on an NVMe drive, but because my motherboard doesn't support booting from NVMe, I have to have my boot partition installed on a separate drive. I am unsure about how to do this. I'm running UEFI. I've seen other people who have similar setups, but I'm unsure of what specific commands to use in my case.

My setup from `lsblk`:

```
sda           8:0    0  931.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0      1G  0 part 

nvme0n1     259:0    0  465.8G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0  465.8G  0 part
```

I have my root paratition, on `nvme0n1` and want to have grub installed on `sda1`. I'm running Arch linux.

**Edit:**

I started to install grub with the help of the wiki, I want it installed on partition `sda1`. So I went ahead and set the file system with `mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/sda1`

I then mounted my already existing root partition `nvme0n1p1` to `/mnt` with `mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt` and then mounted my boot partition with `mount --mkdir /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot`. Then I chrooted into the drive with `chroot /mnt`

After I chrooted, I tried installing grub with `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=GRUB`
but when I do that I get this error

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find a device for /boot (is /dev mounted?).
```

**Edit #2:**

Okay so when my root partition was mounted I somehow managed to accidentally erase all of it, thankfully there was nothing important on there, and so I decided to reinstall everything from scratch. I created a root partition on `nvme0n1p1` and created an EFI partition on `sda` with `fdisk` and proceeded to install as normal. when I got to the point of installing grub, I mounted the root drive to `/mnt` and then `arch-chroot`ed into it a mounted `/dev/sda1` to `/boot/EFI` and then ran the `grub-install` command and it installed, no errors reported. When I went to reboot the system, I was entered into grub rescue mode.

```
error: no such device: 130d6893-1d77-4068-bd71-bd95b7aee837.
error: unknown filesystem
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB . And you must have a very weird motherboard that supports NVMe drives but can't boot from it? Never heard of such oddity.

Comment: My motherboard doesn't have an m.2 slot, so I use a pcie adapter, that is why I can't boot from it. I'm able to access data on it just fine though.

Comment: Ah OK, that explains it (but some can boot from added PCIe devices). So you have to have the ESP (EFI System Partition) in `sda` (not `sda1` which is a partition unless that is already an ESP). The official guide above should be enough then. If you don't understand something make sure to [edit] the question to update it and reflect where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: Okay thanks, I have that `sda1` partition set because, I want to install grub on only that partition, not the whole drive, because I plan to use the rest of the drive as general storage.

Comment: Either use [arch-chroot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/chroot#Using_arch-chroot) or [chroot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/chroot#Using_chroot) 
with additional mounts.

Comment: You don't install bootloaders in any partition. In UEFI mode it must be installed, again, in the ESP and the ESP is a special partition with specific characteristics, hence my note before. If not intended for multiple OSes it can be as small as 100MB or even less. And again, the linked guide has enough additional links to understand all of this. And you must understand all of this or you'll end up making mistakes.

Comment: Don't forget to [set the partition type](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/EFI_system_partition#GPT_partitioned_disks) of the 
ESP with fdisk (`1` in the list of partition types) or gdisk (type `ef00`).

Comment: It could be that GRUB didn't detect your NVMe. Can you see your disk/root partition if you type `ls` in the GRUB shell (probably `ls (hd1,gpt1)`)?